# ¿Cómo obtener los atributos de un objeto JSON que vienen como string?

Tags: c#, json, jsonobject

Tengo un string llamado *respuesta*:

```
string respuesta=obtieneValoresJson();
```

y el valor de la respuesta es:

```json
{
"rut_emisor": "77246584-K",
"rut_envia": "8306211-8",
"trackid": 10264016025,
"fecha_recepcion": "2023-10-05 18:42:29",
"estado": "REC",
"file": "Envio_DTE_T39_F25432.xml"
}
```

Me gustaría saber cómo capturo esos valores, por ejemplo *rut_emisor*, *rut_envia* y todos los atributos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para deserializar un JSON en C# y obtener un atributo específico, puedes seguir estos pasos utilizando la biblioteca `System.Text.Json`:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace DeserializeJSON
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Tu JSON
            string jsonString = "{\"rut_emisor\": \"77246584-K\", \"rut_envia\": \"8306211-8\", \"trackid\": 10264016025, \"fecha_recepcion\": \"2023-10-05 18:42:29\", \"estado\": \"REC\", \"file\": \"Envio_DTE_T39_F25432.xml\" }";

            // Deserializa el JSON en un objeto
            var objetoDeserializado = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonString);

            // Obtiene un atributo en específico
            string rutEmisor = objetoDeserializado.rut_emisor;

            // Imprime el resultado
            Console.WriteLine("RUT Emisor: " + rutEmisor);
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public string rut_emisor { get; set; }
        public string rut_envia { get; set; }
        public long trackid { get; set; }
        public DateTime fecha_recepcion { get; set; }
        public string estado { get; set; }
        public string file { get; set; }
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, hemos definido una clase `MyClass` que tiene propiedades correspondientes a los atributos en el JSON. Luego, utilizamos `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonString)` para deserializar el JSON en un objeto de tipo `MyClass` y obtener el valor del atributo `rut_emisor`.

Asegúrate de agregar un using a `System.Text.Json` en tu archivo para usar `JsonSerializer`.